# Laravel 5 route protection

Tags: laravel, routes

Assume we´ve got a User and Conversation model with a many-to-many relation.

```
class User extends Model ... {

    public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation');
    }

}


class Conversation extends Model {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

Besides authentication (logging in) which comes out of the box with laravel: How can I protect a specific conversation route for it´s related users?

Which would be the most maintainable way to achieve this? Middleware? Guard? Route model binding? ... right now I´m a bit lost ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. In this case you'd be best off using Laravel's [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization) features. Here are the differences:

1. **Middleware:** used to run logic based on either routes or logged in / logged out state. So, if you want to block the conversations entirely from non-logged in users, use a middleware.
2. **Authorization (policies):** not to be confused with **authentication**, is intended for cases where the rules to block someone is not based on route but on some other, more specific reason. These reasons can be anything from roles, to teams, entity ownership, and so on. If you wanted to hide a conversation to only those in the conversation, you can create a policy that kicks the user back to their previous page if they were not in the conversation.

Here's a quick policy you might create:

```
class ConversationPolicy {

    public function view(User $user, Conversation $conv) {
        return in_array($user->id, $conv->users->pluck('id'));
    }

}
```

You could check your policy in a controller like the following:

```
if($request->user()->can('view', $conversation))
{
   return view('conversation', ['conversation' => $conversation]);
}

return back()->withError('You are not authorized to view this conversation');
```

Just be aware you'll have to bind this policy in the AuthServiceProvider before it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. Works like a charm. It should be ```$conv->users->pluck('id')``` without parenthesis right?

Comment: Yep. Good catch. Updated original to fix.